# How do I transform polygon into rect on hover?

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I would like to create an interactive map of the USA. Whenever a user puts their mouse over a state, I would like the polygon to transform into a hovering rectangle filled with information that the user can click. Would I need to create a rect that is normally invisible until a mouse hovers over it or is there another way to go about this? Below is what I would like to happen, I'm not sure how to execute it.

```
    <polygon
    points="19,133 81,152 67,210 132,309 134,319 134,330 127,340 126,350 81,348 79,339 79,329 69,322 60,310 46,299 
    35,296 37,285 24,256 22,247 27,239 20,234 20,226 20,221 19,214 9,195 8,183 8,172 8,166 13,162 15,140"/>
    <rect x="33" y="220" rx="20" ry="20" width="250" height="150">
        <animateTransform attributeName="x" from="10" to="200" dur="3s" fill="freeze"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="scale" from="0" to="1" dur="3s"/>
    </rect>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps. I'm not sure when you want the different bits to become visible/invisible but I'm sure you can adjust things as you see fit.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<polygon
    points="19,133 81,152 67,210 132,309 134,319 134,330 127,340 126,350 81,348 79,339 79,329 69,322 60,310 46,299 
    35,296 37,285 24,256 22,247 27,239 20,234 20,226 20,221 19,214 9,195 8,183 8,172 8,166 13,162 15,140">
        <set id="a1" attributeName="visibility" to="hidden" begin="mouseover" dur="3s"/>
</polygon>
    <rect x="33" y="220" rx="20" ry="20" width="250" height="150" transform="scale(0)" visibility="hidden" pointer-events="all">
        <set attributeName="visibility" to="visible" begin="a1.begin" dur="10s"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="x" begin="a1.begin" from="10" to="200" dur="3s" fill="freeze"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" begin="a1.begin" type="scale" from="0" to="1" dur="3s" fill="freeze"/>
    </rect>
</svg>
```